# Splinter- Web Scraping href by find_partial_text

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup, splinter

I am new to web scraping and am trying to retrieve an href from an HTML page using Splinter and Beautiful Soup. Here is my code

```
# hem1
url="https://astrogeology.usgs.gov/search/map/Mars/Viking/cerberus_enhanced"
browser.visit(url)
hem1=browser.find_link_by_partial_text('Sample').get("href")
```

This receives the error

> AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'get'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You get this error because `browser.find_link_by_partial_text('Sample')` returns an [`ElementList`](https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/element-list.html#splinter.element_list.ElementList). To get an element out of it, you need to use indexes.

Example:

```
hem1=browser.find_link_by_partial_text('Sample')
first_element = hem1[0]
```

To get the `href` you can use the below line:

```
hem1[0]['href']
```

More info about `find_link_by_partial_text()` : https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.find_link_by_partial_text

Comment: This returns a splinter element that converts back to "sample", the partial text, as opposed to the href that accompanies it. Is there any way to "get" the associated href?

Comment: Please approve the answer if this helped you :)

Comment: How do I approve? I voted it up, but since I haven't answered any questions, stack overflow does not show it

Comment: You can click the tick on the left side of the answer